# Generate Pairs with Labels from Arrays in a List in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Given a list of arrays with different sizes, I want to label pairs within one array as similar (1) and pairs from different arrays as dissimilar (0).

Assume we have this list:

```
a = [[0, 1, 3],[4, 2]]
```

The Result should look like this:

```
pairs = [[0,1],[0,3],[0,4],[0,2],[1,0],[1,3],[1,4],...,[4,2],[4,1],...]
label = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ... , 1, 0, ...]
```

However the order of the pairs does not matter.

Any tips would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: look into the ```itertools``` module

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
from itertools import permutations

a=[[0,1,3],[4,2]]
a1=a[0]
a2=a[1]

a3=a1.copy()
a3.extend(a2)

perms=list(permutations(a3, 2))
print(perms)
new_arr = []

for i in perms:
    if (i[0] in a1 and i[1] in a1) or (i[0] in a2 and i[1] in a2):
        new_arr.append(1)
    else:
        new_arr.append(0)

print(new_arr)
```